# Can Drupal Commerce and Ubercart be installed on the same site?

Tags: 7, commerce, ubercart

Can Drupal Commerce and Ubercart be installed on the same site or will they conflict with eachother?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two modules define the same menu entries - so you can use only one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, they can be installed together. In admin menu there will be two tabs Store etc. Maybe there are some conflicts but I have not noticed yet.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Is your answer meant to show that what Eugene wrote is no longer valid?Have you checked it?

Comment: I am checking it right now. It works but maybe there are some issues. In several days I will post my experience.

Comment: After checking some functionalities, I must say that there are some issues with compatibilites of order and cart for users (for an administer it is OK). So, it is not recommended to install these two systems at the same time.